# BasedOnSchemas option in Tridion 2011 CoreService

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

I'm trying to understand the purpose of the BasedOnSchemas option in the OrganizationalItemItemsFilterData filter.

The documentation clearly states: 
"Gets or sets the BasedOnSchemas condition to return only items that are using the given schemas"
So it should be possible to only retrieve components of a specific schema, right?

here's my code:

```cs
LinkToSchemaData[] schemaLinks = new[] { 
        new LinkToSchemaData { IdRef = "tcm:113-362325-8" } 
    };

OrganizationalItemItemsFilterData filter = 
    new OrganizationalItemItemsFilterData();

filter.BaseColumns = ListBaseColumns.Extended;
filter.ItemTypes = new ItemType[] { ItemType.Component };
filter.Recursive = true;
filter.BasedOnSchemas = schemaLinks;

XElement items = client.GetListXml("tcm:113-14192-2", filter);
```

The XElement `items` will however, contain multiple types of components, not only those of schema tcm:113-362325-8

How can I retrieve only those components that are based on my schema?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using both `BasedOnSchemas` and `Recursive = true` is not supported. Remove the the recursiveness and you'll find that the schema filter works.

If you want to get a "recursive" list of all Components for a certain Schema, consider doing a WhereUsed on the Schema.

```
GetListXml("tcm:5-59-8", new UsingItemsFilterData())
```

Comment: tnx Frank, after removing the recursive option my list does only contain those specific items.
Is this mentioned anywhere in the documentation?
I will have a look at the WhereUsedFilterData...

Comment: Why isn't this in the Content Manager Core Service API Reference CHM?!